# Question about in c++, vector push_back(),I am not sure how to fill inside the()

Tags: c++, vector

I have a question about `vector` `push_back()`.I am writing a code to acquire image into the buffer and store them inside a `vector`.I checked that I may need to use `push_back()`,But I am not sure right now how should I format `pImageBuffer` that I can store it into the `vector`.Maybe it is another easy question,but I have been trying a whole morning but still confused.I hope someone can give me some light.Thanks very much in advance!!

the Result.Buffer() is from a camera SDK,it will renew by StreamGrabber.QueueBuffer.My problem is whenever I build I got error like :

std::vector<_Ty>::push_back': Konvertierung des Parameters 1 von 'const uint8_t *' in 'unsigned char *const &' not possible

My code is some how like this.
....

```
std::vector<uint8_t *> images(100);// here is the problem ,it needs a "const",or    delete const down const uint8_t *pImageBuffe.Thanks very much guys for your answers!!!

while(1){
....

 const uint8_t *pImageBuffer = (uint8_t *) Result.Buffer();// Here I get the image data

 images.push_back(pImageBuffer);// This is obvious wrong,but I am not sure in side (),what should I do 

 StreamGrabber.QueueBuffer(Result.Handle(), NULL);

...
}
```

Comment: As long as the call to Results.Buffer() allocates a new buffer, the code you have is correct. If Results.Buffer() re-uses the old buffer, this will cause problems.

Comment: You say it is obviously wrong ... it isn't obvious to me. If you are getting a compile error, please include the error message. If something else is going wrong, describe it. In general, you won't get far if your question is "I am trying to do this, and here is my code, but it doesn't work." (Having said that, I tried my best to answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `const uint8_t*`, but your container stores `uint8_t*`.

Also note that you're adding a 100<sup>th</sup>, 101<sup>st</sup>, 102<sup>nd</sup> element there, not filling the 0<sup>th</sup>, 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup>...

You may want:

```
std::vector<const uint8_t*> images(100);

size_t i = 0;
while (i < 100) {
  // ..
  const uint8_t* pImageBuffer = (uint8_t*)Result.Buffer();
  images[i++] = pImageBuffer;
  // ..
}
```

Or you may want:

```
std::vector<const uint8_t*> images;

while (true) {
  // ..
  const uint8_t* pImageBuffer = (uint8_t*)Result.Buffer();
  images.push_back(pImageBuffer);
  // ..
}
```

Or you may want combinations without the `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `const` :

```
std::vector<uint8_t *> images;//(100);

while(whateverCondition)
{
   uint8_t *pImageBuffer = (uint8_t *) Result.Buffer();
   images.push_back(pImageBuffer);
}
```

Make sure `Buffer()` function allocates new buffer everytime its called.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the vector elements needs to be the same as the type of the thing you are putting inside it (or at least compatible).

I suspect what is wrong is that you are pushing a value of type `const uint8_t *` into a vector whose elements have type `uint8_t *` -- that is, you are trying to convert a const pointer into a non-const pointer.

Change the vector's type to `std::vector<const uint8_t *>`.

Comment: That is of no consideration- only if it was `uint8_t* const` would this be the case.

Comment: Nope, then it wouldn't matter. See [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.5). `uint8_t* const` means "constant pointer to a uint8_t," which wouldn't matter if you copied the pointer. `const uint8_t*` means "pointer to constant uint8_t," which *does* matter if you pass the pointer around.

Comment: My mistake- I always get the two mixed up.

Comment: @DeadMG No worries ... I had to look up C++ FAQ myself to remember.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, the only thing which is really wrong is that you're trying to put a `const uint8_t *` into a vector of `uint8_t *`. Try removing the `const` and see whether that works better.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `(100)` - and you need to be consistent about `const`.